# Loop through checked checkboxes in grid and get lable values WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

i have a grid,inside that grid there's a `stackpanel` inside which  there is one `Checkbox` and 2 `TextBlocks`. The `XAML` is :

```
  <Grid x:name="maingrid" >
    <Stackpanel x:name="panel1">
       <Checkbox height="10" width="10"/>
       <Textblock x:name="name1" text="a"/>
       <Textblock x:name="name2" text="b"/>
       <Textblock x:name="name3" text="c"/>
     </Stackpanel>
   </Grid>
```

Now, the thing is, inside `MainGrid`, I am dynamically adding `panel1` (the stackpanel) based on a list of random text. Anyway, what i want is , when i check the checkbox, the releavent `Stackpanel(panel1)`'s textblock values(`name1`,`name2`,`name3`'s values) would be passed to a `List(Of string)` from where I can get the values of the three textblocks of each checked `Checkboxes` in stackpanels... Somewhat like the `DataGrid`/`DataGridView` (winforms) ..

I beg your pardon if I failed to describe my wants properly but I hope you can understand what I'm looking for. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982806/how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-in-a-tabcontrol-using-wpf) but as my motive and situation is entirely different, i can't really make use of the answer in that post... Any help/explanation of my idea ?

**UPDATE : A more logical/better explanation**
If i have a `UserControl` with 1 `checkbox` and 2 `textblocks` and populate a `Window`'s grid with the usercontrol based on datarows derived from a datatable, how do i get the textblock values of the checked checkboxes of the 
`UserControl`?

Comment: The question is unclear. You wrote "dynamically adding", but posted XAML, that contains stack panel. Do you want to insert number of `StackPanel`s inside grid, or there will always be a single one? If answer is "several", will `StackPanel`s content be the same, or the number of `TextBlock`s can vary? Can user check multiple checkboxes?

Comment: yes...i want to add multiple stackpanels inside `MianGrid` and the stackpanels content will be the same (1 checkbox and 2 textblocks) and yes, user can check multiple chekcboxes

Comment: why not use `DataGrid` instead? [DataGrid+DataTable example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206066/1506454)

Comment: i agree with u but i asked a question yesterday on how to bind data to datagrid in wpf from access database but got no answers....So i thought of making one my own ....

Comment: @F.raiyan, you should have done a better research

Comment: Easy @ASh, I see he did nothing wrong.

Comment: @RedWei, you just can't see deleted questions

Comment: Pardon if i asked the question in the wrong manner..Did i fail to explain my problem ?

Comment: my yseterday's qustion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011951/bind-observeable-collection-to-database-datatable-and-datagrid-to-observeablecol)

Comment: @F.raiyan you want to do this with MVVM or no MVVM.

Comment: actually i never used MVVM before,i am really new to WPF and these `model/viewmodel` stuff....I'ld rather stick to NO MVVM way only if u r kind enough to help me

Comment: ow and one more thing,as i mentioned about a `Checkbox` in my post, the template of the checkbox is customized , will be able to apply that template/style to the datagrid's checkboxes as well ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to apply that style. I am writing the answer.

Comment: thank u soo much for your patience.. It's a pleasure ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-MVVM way

To access your value inside your customized UserControl. You need a UserControl with a name on every control in it and then when you use, you just call it's name.

In MyUserControl.xaml:

```
<Stackpanel x:name="panel1">
   <Checkbox x:name="checkbox1" height="10" width="10"/> <!-- Apply your style here -->
   <Textblock x:name="name1" text="a"/>
   <Textblock x:name="name2" text="b"/>
   <Textblock x:name="name3" text="c"/>
</Stackpanel>
```

In MyWindow.xaml:

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControlInstance"/>
<Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />
```

In MyWindow.cs:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (myUserControlInstance.checkbox1.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
             var checkboxValue=myUserControlInstance.checkbox1.IsChecked.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i have multiple useontrols and multiple checked checkboxes,will be able to loop through them ?

Comment: Solution 1: You just need to name every UserControl you have added and loop though that name list.
Solution 2: You need to loop on every UserControl without it's name.

Comment: How can i name every usecontrol as i'm adding them dynamically based on datarows from a datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to work with XAML as you worked with WinForms. It's a dead-end.
Use MVVM, data binding, and work with data first of all.

Here's sample view model for "stack panel"s and their content:

```
public sealed class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name1 { get; set; }

    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

`ViewModelBase` is a basic `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation (google it).

Next, view model for sample application:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (items == null)
            {
                items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
                items.CollectionChanged += ItemsCollectionChanged;
            }

            return items;
        }
    }

    private void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                // we want to be notified, if IsChecked is changed;
                // ObservableCollection<T> adds one item per time, so, we just using NewItems[0]
                ((ItemViewModel)e.NewItems[0]).PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                // we need to unsibscribe, when removing item from collection,
                // to avoid memory leak
                ((ItemViewModel)e.OldItems[0]).PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // we're interested only in IsCheckedProperty
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ItemViewModel.IsChecked))
        {
            // let's update our list
            UpdateItemTextValues();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateItemTextValues()
    {
        // retrieving NameN property values from checked items as a single list
        var itemTextValues = Items
            .Where(_ => _.IsChecked)
            .Select(_ => new[]
            {
                _.Name1,
                _.Name2
            })
            .SelectMany(_ => _)
            .ToList();

        // do somethig with the list
        Trace.WriteLine(null);

        foreach (var value in itemTextValues)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML. Note, that you don't need `Grid`, use `ItemsControl` instead:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox Content="Check me" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code-behind for `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainViewModel
        {
            Items =
            {
                // these are samle items;
                // you can fill collection the way you want
                new ItemViewModel { Name1 = "A", Name2 = "B" },
                new ItemViewModel { Name1 = "C", Name2 = "D" },
                new ItemViewModel { Name1 = "E", Name2 = "F" },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In case of `UserControl` you must to provide appropriate properties from your control to bind to, and change `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: I know almost nothing about MVVM , so a basic qs: Do i need to create a new project for this  ? How do i really get started ?

Comment: I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) and i'm starting to learn MVVM...after understanding the basics , i'll implement ur result

Comment: You can copy/paste this code to a new WpfApplication project and play with it. In fact, I did the same. Don't be afraid of MVVM - it's not so hard to learn.

Comment: Can i use it in the existing project ?

Comment: Of course you can. But you will need to adapt it to your current code.

Comment: can u review the other answer ? Which method should i go with ? Yours or the other guys answer?

Comment: i posted my yesterday's question on MSDN and someone there said that my biggest issue is that i am using an ACCESS database..any comments on this ?

Comment: The choice is yours. My answer relies on rather complex WPF production code. I don't recommend to go that way (I mean the second answer).

Comment: To be honest, you should learn MVVM and adapt it into your WPF program. This will take some times to practise before you can adapt it properly and easily. So if you need your program ugently, just go for my answer, if it is not, start to learn MVVM. I can help you to learn MVVM, just send me inbox of your Discord.

Comment: can u start a chat with me >

Comment: Please go to my profile, you will see my email here. Send me an email.

Comment: i eamiled u,please see it